# Python Ultimate tic tac toe for two players

Tags: python, python-3.x, tic-tac-toe

i has this project where i need to modify an exiting code, in this case is the ultimate tic tac toe, specifically this one: https://github.com/pulkitmaloo/Ultimate-Tic-Tac-Toe

the modification i require is to make it a two players game but i don't even know how to begin, there are a lot of functions i don't really understand. im just a beginner in this python thing.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
@author: Pulkit Maloo
"""

from math import inf
from collections import Counter
import itertools
from time import time


TIME_LIMIT = 1


def index(x, y):
    x -= 1
    y -= 1
    return ((x//3)*27) + ((x % 3)*3) + ((y//3)*9) + (y % 3)


def box(x, y):
    return index(x, y) // 9


def next_box(i):
    return i % 9


def indices_of_box(b):
    return list(range(b*9, b*9 + 9))


def print_board(state):
    for row in range(1, 10):
        row_str = ["|"]
        for col in range(1, 10):
            row_str += [state[index(row, col)]]
            if (col) % 3 == 0:
                row_str += ["|"]
        if (row-1) % 3 == 0:
            print("-"*(len(row_str)*2-1))
        print(" ".join(row_str))
    print("-"*(len(row_str)*2-1))
    
    


def add_piece(state, move, player):
    if not isinstance(move, int):
        move = index(move[0], move[1])
    return state[: move] + player + state[move+1:]


def update_box_won(state):
    temp_box_win = ["."] * 9
    for b in range(9):
        idxs_box = indices_of_box(b)
        box_str = state[idxs_box[0]: idxs_box[-1]+1]
        temp_box_win[b] = check_small_box(box_str)
    return temp_box_win


def check_small_box(box_str):
    global possible_goals
    for idxs in possible_goals:
        (x, y, z) = idxs
        if (box_str[x] == box_str[y] == box_str[z]) and box_str[x] != ".":
            return box_str[x]
    return "."


def possible_moves(last_move):
    global box_won
    if not isinstance(last_move, int):
        last_move = index(last_move[0], last_move[1])
    box_to_play = next_box(last_move)
    idxs = indices_of_box(box_to_play)
    if box_won[box_to_play] != ".":
        pi_2d = [indices_of_box(b) for b in range(9) if box_won[b] == "."]
        possible_indices = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(pi_2d))
    else:
        possible_indices = idxs
    return possible_indices


def successors(state, player, last_move):
    succ = []
    moves_idx = []
    possible_indexes = possible_moves(last_move)
    for idx in possible_indexes:
        if state[idx] == ".":
            moves_idx.append(idx)
            succ.append(add_piece(state, idx, player))
    return zip(succ, moves_idx)


def print_successors(state, player, last_move):
    for st in successors(state, player, last_move):
        print_board(st[0])


def opponent(p):
    return "O" if p == "X" else "X"


def evaluate_small_box(box_str, player):
    global possible_goals
    score = 0
    three = Counter(player * 3)
    two = Counter(player * 2 + ".")
    one = Counter(player * 1 + "." * 2)
    three_opponent = Counter(opponent(player) * 3)
    two_opponent = Counter(opponent(player) * 2 + ".")
    one_opponent = Counter(opponent(player) * 1 + "." * 2)

    for idxs in possible_goals:
        (x, y, z) = idxs
        current = Counter([box_str[x], box_str[y], box_str[z]])

        if current == three:
            score += 100
        elif current == two:
            score += 10
        elif current == one:
            score += 1
        elif current == three_opponent:
            score -= 100
            return score
        elif current == two_opponent:
            score -= 10
        elif current == one_opponent:
            score -= 1

    return score


def evaluate(state, last_move, player):
    global box_won
    score = 0
    score += evaluate_small_box(box_won, player) * 200
    for b in range(9):
        idxs = indices_of_box(b)
        box_str = state[idxs[0]: idxs[-1]+1]
        score += evaluate_small_box(box_str, player)
    return score


def minimax(state, last_move, player, depth, s_time):
    succ = successors(state, player, last_move)
    best_move = (-inf, None)
    for s in succ:
        val = min_turn(s[0], s[1], opponent(player), depth-1, s_time,
                       -inf, inf)
        if val > best_move[0]:
            best_move = (val, s)
#        print("val = ", val)
#        print_board(s[0])
    return best_move[1]


def min_turn(state, last_move, player, depth, s_time, alpha, beta):
    global box_won
    if depth <= 0 or check_small_box(box_won) != ".":# or time() - s_time >= 10:
        return evaluate(state, last_move, opponent(player))
    succ = successors(state, player, last_move)
    for s in succ:
        val = max_turn(s[0], s[1], opponent(player), depth-1, s_time,
                       alpha, beta)
        if val < beta:
            beta = val
        if alpha >= beta:
            break
    return beta


def max_turn(state, last_move, player, depth, s_time, alpha, beta):
    global box_won
    if depth <= 0 or check_small_box(box_won) != ".":# or time() - s_time >= 20:
        return evaluate(state, last_move, player)
    succ = successors(state, player, last_move)
    for s in succ:
        val = min_turn(s[0], s[1], opponent(player), depth-1, s_time,
                       alpha, beta)
        if alpha < val:
            alpha = val
        if alpha >= beta:
            break
    return alpha


def valid_input(state, move):
    global box_won
    if not (0 < move[0] < 10 and 0 < move[1] < 10):
        return False
    if box_won[box(move[0], move[1])] != ".":
        return False
    if state[index(move[0], move[1])] != ".":
        return False
    return True


def take_input(state, bot_move):
    print("#" * 40)
    all_open_flag = False
    if bot_move == -1 or len(possible_moves(bot_move)) > 9:
        all_open_flag = True
    if all_open_flag:
        print("Tira donde quieras!")
    else:
        box_dict = {0: "Esquina superior izquierda", 1: "Arriba del Centro", 2: "Esquina superior Derecha",
                    3: "Izquierda del Centro", 4: "Centro", 5: "Derecha del Centro",
                    6: "Esquina inferior izquierda", 7: "Abajo de centro", 8: "Esquina inferior Derecha"}
        print("Donde quieres tirar la 'X'? DEBE SER EN EL CUADRANTE: ~"
              + box_dict[next_box(bot_move)])
    x = int(input("Renglon = "))
    if x == -1:
        raise SystemExit
    y = int(input("Columna = "))
    print("")
    if bot_move != -1 and index(x, y) not in possible_moves(bot_move):
        raise ValueError
    if not valid_input(state, (x, y)):
        raise ValueError
    return (x, y)


def game(state="." * 81, depth=20):
    global box_won, possible_goals 
    possible_goals = [(0, 4, 8), (2, 4, 6)]
    possible_goals += [(i, i+3, i+6) for i in range(3)]
    possible_goals += [(3*i, 3*i+1, 3*i+2) for i in range(3)]
    box_won = update_box_won(state)
    print_board(state)
    bot_move = -1

    while True:
        try:
            user_move = take_input(state, bot_move)
        except ValueError:
            print("INGRESA OTROS VALORES")
            print_board(state)
            continue
        except SystemError:
            print("Error ¡Juego Detenido!")
            break

        user_state = add_piece(state, user_move, "X")
        print_board(user_state)
        box_won = update_box_won(user_state)

        game_won = check_small_box(box_won)
        if game_won != ".":
            state = user_state
            break

        print("Espera un momento...")
        s_time = time()
        bot_state, bot_move = minimax(user_state, user_move, "O", depth,
                                      s_time)

        print("#" * 40)
        print("La computadora puso 'O' en", bot_move, "\n")
        print_board(bot_state)
        state = bot_state
        box_won = update_box_won(bot_state)
        game_won = check_small_box(box_won)
        if game_won != ".":
            break

    if game_won == "X":
        print("¡Ganaste este Cuadrante! selecciona otro para seguir jugando")
    else:
        print("Perdiste este cuadrante!, selecciona otro para seguir jugando ")

    return state


if __name__ == "__main__":

    INITIAL_STATE = "." * 81
    final_state = game(INITIAL_STATE, depth=5)
```

Comment: So, you want to know what does code's functions do?